# apache2 force proxy for specific url on a subdomain

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, virtual-hosts

I have a site that has dynamic virtual subdomains using mod_rewrite, as defined like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName    example.com
    ServerAlias    *.example.com

    DocumentRoot    /var/www/example.com/www

    RewriteEngine    on
    RewriteCond    %{HTTP_HOST}    ^[^.]+\.examle.com$
    RewriteRule    ^(.+)            %{HTTP_HOST}$1    [C]

    RewriteRule    ^([^.]+)\.example.com(.*)    /var/www/example.com/$1$2

</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that I want a specific url, say subdomain.example.com/CONTROL/ to point back to www.example.com/ using a proxy (not url redirecting).

I have tried adding:

```
    RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.example.com/CONTROL(.*)    /var/www/example.com/www$2 [P]
```

But that didn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Surely this belongs on serverfault?

Comment: Maybe.  I'll give that a shot.

Comment: New URL: http://serverfault.com/questions/62854/apache2-force-proxy-for-specific-url-on-a-subdomain